# RTABmap localization error

Tags: slam, navigation, ros-melodic, rtabmap

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I recently got this error while localizing with RTABmap:

```
Memory.cpp:739::update() The working memory is empty and the memory is not incremental (Mem/IncrementalMemory=False), no loop closure can be detected! Please set Mem/IncrementalMemory=true to increase the memory with new images or decrease the STM size (which is 1 including the new one added).
[ WARN] (2019-07-11 17:17:24.941) Rtabmap.cpp:3369::getPaths() path.size()=0!? nearestId=0 ids=1, aborting...
[FATAL] (2019-07-11 17:17:24.947) Rtabmap.cpp:2743::process() Condition (_memory->getSignature(id) != 0) not met! [id=1]
```

What is the reason behind it and how can I avoid it?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/328282/rtabmap-localization-error/) by [EdwardNur](https://answers.ros.org/users/39496/edwardnur/) on ROS Answers with karma: 115 on 2019-07-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The map is empty and localization mode is enabled. I could not reproduce the fatal error though (on latest version). Make sure a map is previously created and you don't restart rtabmap in localization mode (`Mem/IncrementalMemory=false`) with "`--delete_db_on_start`" argument.

---

Originally posted by [matlabbe](https://answers.ros.org/users/20914/matlabbe/) with karma: 6409 on 2019-07-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [EdwardNur](https://answers.ros.org/users/39496/edwardnur/) on 2019-07-11**:
@matlabbe so when I do the localization mode, I should make `Mem/IncrementalMemory=false` ? Also, I am using 0.17 version, I guess the latest one is 0.19? Does it have this version in binary and would you recommend me to upgrading?

**Comment by [matlabbe](https://answers.ros.org/users/20914/matlabbe/) on 2019-07-11**:
When you go in localization mode, **you should have previously created a map**. The warning above says that you don't have a map, so you are localizing on nothing. 0.19 is available on melodic, though it is not the problem here.